# How to integrate with external API through GeneralBots

Tags: bots

#generalbots - I would like to integrate my bot with an external API, but i don't know the process of define URL, Headers and Params and setup the return JSON.

I didn't try anything yet. I am currently trying to develop this process.

Comment: Shif iher ne google plak edhe jep naj shembull sepse nuk te kthejne kshu pergjigje kta kur nuk perpiqesh.

Answer (score 0):

To define HTTP headers in a GET keyword call use the following:

```html
SET HTTP USERNAME = "YOUR_USERNAME" 

SET HTTP PASSWORD = "YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

With these headers defined, it is possible to call the authenticated GET, after asking for a numeric code in the conversation:

```html
TALK "Please, what is your code?"
HEAR code as NUMBER

data = GET "https://api.domain.com/lists/customers?code=" + code

TALK "Hello, " + data.name + "."
```

Please, refer to the BotBook repository for more information: https://github.com/GeneralBots/BotBook/blob/master/book/chapter-05-gbdialog-reference.md#using-post-data.